# Can I boot the latest Ubuntu with a USB just like the hard disk drive?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

Can I treat my 128 GB USB like the internal hard disk drive (HDD) and make an Ubuntu OS installation on it and whenever I want, boot the OS from it, and be as fast as using the original OS with a HDD?

My USB is the new fast 3.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use a USB stick for a normal install? (to get platform adaptability)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/600258/can-i-use-a-usb-stick-for-a-normal-install-to-get-platform-adaptability)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here you will find comprehensive instructions on how to do it:

**[How to install Ubuntu on an USB stick](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307802/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-usb-stick)**

But the performance will not be the same as if you install it on a HDD or SSD.

Comment: Thank you.but why it won't be as fast as HDD or SSD.i read that usb 3.0 is 10 times more faster than 2.0.So,shouldn't it be as fast?

Comment: @Nuser : Even if USB 3.0 is faster than USB 2.0 - an operating system still works not as fast as on an internal disk. You can find many articles on this topic on the internet. :)

Comment: @Nuser: yes you can get performance as fast as on an SSD on a USB 3.0 stick. [look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600258/can-i-use-a-usb-stick-for-a-normal-install-to-get-platform-adaptability) how to do it.  (your current USB stick will probably have to be replaced unless you paid around 75€ for it)

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, it should work with a persistent USB.

While creating the USB startup disk from an Ubuntu ISO file, make sure you select the option "Stored in reserved extra space" for storage of documents and settings. You should allocate a good amount of space to this heading if you are going to use Ubuntu from your USB for a long time.

Once the startup disk has been created, plug it into the computer you want to use it on, boot from it and select try ubuntu to use Ubuntu direct from your USB without having to install it.