# Is it possible to install full Ubuntu on a 32 GB flashdrive from the ISO on a bootable drive?

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, usb-installation

I want to be able to run the full Ubuntu desktop from a 32GB Strontium flashdrive but I can't seem to make the proper partitions. These are the steps I took:

1. I made a bootable drive from a 16GB drive I had lying around with
   Rufus
2. I booted up the trial Ubuntu from the 16GB USB drive and tried to
   install Ubuntu directly onto the 32GB drive using the 'something
   else' tab and the 3 following partitions ([198Mb FAT32 EFI System
   Partition], [18.63 GB ext4 Primary Partition], [11.34 GB swap
   Logical Partition])
3. After the installation was complete I booted Ubuntu from the 32GB
   USB drive and it booted up but it is essentially unusable.

It takes about 2 minutes for every mouse click to respond and I believe it has to do with the way I partitioned the drive but I honestly don't know anymore at this point. Frustration has taken over my mind and I need help.

Comment: If it boots then it has nothing to do with the partitions. Installing in a USB flash drive makes it automatically a lot slower. And if you have a Nvidia graphics card then you also need drivers for optimal performance.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/307802/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-usb-stick?noredirect=1&lq=1[How to install Ubuntu on a USB stick][1]

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Does this also mean it would run a lot slower from an external hard drive?

Comment: It all depends on the specific hardware, particularly the USB ports' and drive's generation.

Comment: I have ran ubuntu on average external hard drives connected to USB2 and did not find it much slower, but that just browsing and email and watching videos.  Doing something like video editing be different.  USB sticks are usually decent.

Comment: If you are used to using a SSD drive, then using a USB/ext HD will be very slow.

Comment: What works for me for USB install that boots in BIOS and UEFI,  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142544/standard-uses-of-usb-if-ubuntu-is-installed/1142675#1142675 Nowadays Ubuntu should mostly be running in RAM. It is a good idea to check the ISO's MD5SUM.